# Transmitting sine wave wave through ESP-NOW

Tags: c++, esp32, wireless, sine-wave, esp-now

I am currently studying this post, and if I can use the code in this article, I believe it can solve my problem. However, when I use his code, I cannot measure the waveform on the receivier's pin_DAC. Can someone help me take a look at the code in this article to see if there are any problem ? Thank you all.
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/esp32-and-esp-now-for-audio-streaming-slow-acknowledge-from-receiver/1055192

This is the code I am using on the transmiter:

```
#define CONFIG_ESP32_WIFI_AMPDU_RX_ENABLED 0
#define CONFIG_ESP32_WIFI_AMPDU_TX_ENABLED 0

#include <esp_now.h>
#include <esp_wifi.h>
#include <driver/adc.h>
#include <driver/dac.h>

uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0xC0, 0x49, 0xEF, 0xCA, 0x3B, 0x00}; //

uint8_t IN_BUFF[250]={128, 131, 134, 138, 141, 144, 147, 150, 153, 157, 160, 163, 166, 169, 172, 175, 178, 181, 184, 187, 189, 192, 195, 198, 200, 203, 205, 208, 210, 213, 215, 218, 220, 222, 224, 226, 228, 230, 232, 234, 236, 237, 239, 240, 242, 243, 244, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 252, 253, 253, 254, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 254, 254, 254, 253, 253, 252, 251, 250, 249, 248, 247, 246, 245, 244, 242, 241, 240, 238, 236, 235, 233, 231, 229, 227, 225, 223, 221, 219, 216, 214, 212, 209, 207, 204, 202, 199, 196, 194, 191, 188, 185, 182, 179, 176, 173, 170, 167, 164, 161, 158, 155, 152, 149, 146, 142, 139, 136, 133, 130, 126, 123, 120, 117, 114, 110, 107, 104, 101, 98, 95, 92, 89, 86, 83, 80, 77, 74, 71, 68, 65, 62, 60, 57, 54, 52, 49, 47, 44, 42, 40, 37, 35, 33, 31, 29, 27, 25, 23, 21, 20, 18, 16, 15, 14, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 41, 43, 46, 48, 51, 53, 56, 58, 61, 64, 67, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99, 103, 106, 109, 112, 115, 118, 122, 125, 128};
uint8_t OUT_BUFF[250];

volatile uint8_t i=0;
volatile uint8_t sent=1;
volatile uint8_t ack=1;
volatile uint8_t dataReady=0;
volatile uint8_t pin_state=0;

hw_timer_t *My_timer = NULL;

esp_now_peer_info_t peerInfo;

// callback when data is sent
void OnDataSent(const uint8_t *mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status) {
  if(status){
    Serial.println("PACKET ERROR!");
  }
  else{
    ack=1;
  }
}

void IRAM_ATTR sampleADC(){
  //Send a new sine wave byte to DAC1
  dac_output_voltage(DAC_CHANNEL_1, IN_BUFF[i++]);
  if(i==250){
    //If all 250 bytes have been sent, reset counter and prepare esp-now send if previous esp-now frame has been already sent out.
    i=0;
    if(sent){
      memcpy(OUT_BUFF, IN_BUFF, 250);
      dataReady=1;
      sent=0;
    }
  }
}
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  adc1_config_width(ADC_WIDTH_BIT_12);
  adc1_config_channel_atten(ADC1_CHANNEL_0, ADC_ATTEN_DB_0);
  dac_output_enable(DAC_CHANNEL_1);

  // Set device as a Wi-Fi Station
  esp_netif_init();
  wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
  esp_wifi_init(&cfg);
  esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA);
  esp_wifi_set_bandwidth(WIFI_IF_STA, WIFI_BW_HT40);
  esp_wifi_set_storage(WIFI_STORAGE_RAM);
  esp_wifi_set_ps(WIFI_PS_NONE);
  esp_wifi_start();

  // Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }
  esp_wifi_config_espnow_rate(WIFI_IF_STA, WIFI_PHY_RATE_54M);
  esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);
  
  // Register peer
  memcpy(peerInfo.peer_addr, broadcastAddress, 6);
  peerInfo.channel = 0;  
  peerInfo.encrypt = false;
  
  // Add peer        
  if (esp_now_add_peer(&peerInfo) != ESP_OK){
    Serial.println("Failed to add peer");
    return;
  }
  //Setting up a timer interrupt with freq. of 20kHz
  My_timer = timerBegin(0, 8, true);
  timerAttachInterrupt(My_timer, &sampleADC, true);
  timerAlarmWrite(My_timer, 500, true);

  uint8_t started=0;
  while(!started){
    if(Serial.available()>0){
      char c=Serial.read();
      if(c=='1'){
        started=1;
      }
    }
  }
  Serial.println("Entering loop...");
  timerAlarmEnable(My_timer);
}
 
void loop() {
  //If there is new data to send and previous frame was acknowledged by receiver
  if(dataReady && ack){
    esp_err_t result = esp_now_send(broadcastAddress, OUT_BUFF, sizeof(OUT_BUFF));
    sent=1;
    dataReady=0;
    ack=0;
  }
}
```

This is the code for the receiver:

```
#define CONFIG_ESP32_WIFI_AMPDU_RX_ENABLED 0
#define CONFIG_ESP32_WIFI_AMPDU_TX_ENABLED 0

#include <esp_now.h>
#include <esp_wifi.h>
#include <driver/dac.h>

// Structure example to receive data
// Must match the sender structure
uint8_t IN_BUFF[250];
uint8_t OUT_BUFF[250];

volatile uint8_t i=0;
volatile uint8_t data4dac=0;

hw_timer_t *My_timer = NULL;

// callback function that will be executed when data is received
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t * mac, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len) {
  //Copying received bytes to buffer and setting flag for new data for the DAC
  memcpy(IN_BUFF, incomingData, sizeof(IN_BUFF));
  data4dac=1;
}

void IRAM_ATTR writeDAC(){
  //If there is new data for the DAC
  if(data4dac){
    if(i==0){
      //If we finished sending previous 250 bytes, copy new ones from IN_BUFF to OUT_BUFF
      memcpy(OUT_BUFF, IN_BUFF, sizeof(OUT_BUFF));
    }
    dac_output_voltage(DAC_CHANNEL_1, OUT_BUFF[i++]);
    if(i==250){
        //If we reached end of 250 bytes, reset counter and data4dac flag
        i=0;
        data4dac=0;
    }
  }
}
 
void setup() {
  // Initialize Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);
  dac_output_enable(DAC_CHANNEL_1);
  
  // Set device as a Wi-Fi Station
  esp_netif_init();
  wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
  esp_wifi_init(&cfg);
  esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA);
  esp_wifi_set_bandwidth(WIFI_IF_STA, WIFI_BW_HT40);
  esp_wifi_set_storage(WIFI_STORAGE_RAM);
  esp_wifi_set_ps(WIFI_PS_NONE);
  esp_wifi_start();
  
  // Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }
  esp_wifi_config_espnow_rate(WIFI_IF_STA, WIFI_PHY_RATE_54M);

  //Setting up a timer interrupt with a freq. of 20kHz
  My_timer = timerBegin(0, 8, true);
  timerAttachInterrupt(My_timer, &writeDAC, true);
  timerAlarmWrite(My_timer, 500, true);
  timerAlarmEnable(My_timer);
  
  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
}
 
void loop() {
  
}
```

I'm trying to use this code to transmit sine wave.